# How do I select form inputs based on user actions and choices?

Tags: html, forms

Firstly, it was hard to include the question inside the title, so don't bash me.

I have a web framework created by someone and I need to learn to use it.

Let's say I have this HTML form:

```
<form action="servletX" method="get">
    <input name="action" value="search" type="submit">
</form>
```

When the search button is submitted, inside of the servlet, is extracted, based on the word "action" (this is forced by the structure of the framework), what kind of action needs to be made.
One more thing: the action, in this case, "search" is in fact the key for a proprieties file which is read in one of the classes.

My question is: 
How can I implement a search feature, using this framework.

I want to have a field where I enter the data based on which the search is made and 2 submitted buttons (2 options)

Something like this:

```
<form action="servletX" method="get">
    <p>Search
        <input name="action" type="text">
        <input name="action" value="Option1" type="submit">
        <input name="action" value="Option2" type="submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: This is better than one of those questions where *everything* is inside the title, and no description is provided at all.

Comment: There are lots of well documented open source web frameworks (my favourite is http://tapestry.apache.org/). You should use one of them instead of what I assume is an in-house framework without even basic documentation.

Comment: This is not an option for me. :) I need to understand this thing. I MUST! :)

Comment: When I asked the question, I thought there is something in HTML that I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use buttons or radio buttons instead of generic inputs.  They are intended for mutually-exclusive options of the sort required here.